# Router with good Firewall for office - total of 50 computers/devices including wifi devices

Tags: firewalls

I am looking for a good Office Router that can handle good firewall rules, have logs, and ca support about 50 computers/devices connected with wire and wireless.

We had different models before, and even installed dd-wrt, but sometimes when there is some restriction rules, the router just hangs or starts acting weird on some connections.

Router needs to have decent security and firewall.

Thanks

Daniel

Comment: In general shopping questions are off topic on the stackexchange websites. Please refer to the FaQ.

Comment: This is a very broad question... Whats your budget? What requirements do you have in terms of concurrent connections, VPNs, VLANs, etc... Are you familiar with Cisco iOS, or Linux, are you willing to learn a new system? Does this need to be scalable in the future. A general recommendation will do more harm then help. Need more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Lucas has noted, shopping/product suggestions are ... less than welcome(?) on stackexchange sites. I use http://www.smallnetbuilder.com and they are very good. For your wants, they have a security section: http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/security/security-reviews